# How to change for 3D rotation on UIPanGesture?

Tags: iphone, rotation, swipe, iso, uipangesturerecognizer

I have done animation opening a page on tapping on it but now I have to change it for Pan Gesture. How should I start?

```
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    CALayer *layer = ges.view.layer;
    CATransform3D initialTransform = ges.view.layer.transform;
    initialTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1100;
    layer.transform = initialTransform;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-0.0, 0.5);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Scale" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = ges.view.layer.transform;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, -M_PI , 0 , -ges.view.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
    ges.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(ges.view.transform, 0);
    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: do you know how to implement pan gesture...is that your problem ?

Comment: I know how to add Pan Gesture.

Comment: check my answer...does it help ? or you are looking for something else ?

Comment: because i am change angle all of sudden on tap gesture but on panning how i will calculation each and every position?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer myPanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagePanned:)];
[_panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:myPanGesture];
```

**1)  if you want page to turn along with the pan action as user moves the view** then you have to do this way.

```
- (void)imagePanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)iRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    //Calculate transformation based on the translation value of pan gesture, this will be a tricky part

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay: 0 options: 0 animations:
     ^(void) {
        //Apply transformation
     }
    completion: nil];
}
```

**Hope this will help you.**

**Edit : Extended Answer**
**This goes with the first idea**

You just want to rotate the view right ?
then use `CATransform3D`, here you will need to calculate the `iAngle` that we are applying to view.

```
iAngle = //Calculate based on translation
```

where translation is

```
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
```

Then apply transformation to view

```
CATransform3D myTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
myTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
myTransform = CATransform3DRotate(myTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-iAngle), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(d) (d * M_PI / 180)
yourView.layer.transform = myTransform;
```

Comment: panning will call method again and again till it's ends.So your flag logic will not work at ll.Please share another idea.

Comment: check edited answer...flag idea is when you just want to flip the page instantly...I have also given other option..didnt you see that..

Comment: please remove your second option, as it won't give required ans.I saw that.

Comment: Xman , Please see ans and in that if you can do.that will help me .

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the math behind doing it as I don't have code right now to show. Converting finger movement to rotation value is simply a matter of setting up ratios.

For angle value (used in transform):

```
                track_spread     rotation_angle
                ____________  =  ______________

                 movement_x         angle = ?

angle = (rotation_angle * movement_x)/track_spread;
```

WHERE:

```
track_spread   = width_of_your_view (or less e.g. 70% x width_of_your_view)
rotation_angle = the final rotation you want for your view (a constant e.g. 45 degrees)
CGPoint point = [recognizer translationInView:self];
movement_x = abs(point.x); 
angle = the value (in degrees) you are interested in and will input into transform after converting to radians
```

If someone cant figure out and still need code snippet please leave a comment.

Comment: Hello, Can you give an example of it?