# Interactive UIView flip transition

Tags: ios, swift, animation, flip, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have the front and the back of a card. I animate the transition between the two like this:

```
private func flipToBack() {
    UIView.transition(from: frontContainer, to: backContainer, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromRight, .showHideTransitionViews], completion: nil)
}

private func flipToFront() {
    UIView.transition(from: backContainer, to: frontContainer, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .showHideTransitionViews], completion: nil)
}
```

This works perfectly. However, I want to make this animation interactive, so that if the user pans horizontally across the card, the flip animation will advance proportionally. Usually, I would do this kind of interactive animation with a [`UIViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator), but I do not know what property I would animate in the animator without building up the flip animation from scratch.

Is it possible to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, or is there some other alternative to make the flip interactive?

Comment: A clarification: *".... the flip animation will advance proportionally."*. Are you saying that if a user pans *halfway* across a card horizontally it should only "flip" halfway?

Comment: @dfd, yeah. When the user pans halfway across the screen, the flip animation goes halfway (where it would seem like one side disappears and the other appears). As the user scrubs a certain distance, the flip animation goes to that fraction. Then when the user releases, the animation completes. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me. Unfortunately, I'm no help. I *did* preface that it was a clarification. :-) One more question - what should appear if the "scrub" is exactly halfway? A 2D line? I don't know how the flip animation works - I guess one could use a very large `duration` of, say, 15 seconds - but I didn't think it was a true "3D appearance" animation. If I were trying such a thing ("scrubbing") I probably would change it from a "flip" to an "uncover" kind of animation. Wish I could be of more help.

Comment: @dfd, exactly. It would become a vertical 2D line. As I understand it, the 3D affect works by doing a vertical compression gradient and animating the horizontal compression. Sadly, it's hard to replicate the good-looking animation the system has.

Comment: Last shot at helping. I'm guessing to accomplish a flip you'll need to work with `CATransform3DRotate` during the pan. I found two possible helpers but they are old, and one is written in Obj-C. Here's a repo that may help: https://github.com/giacomopiva/FlipNavigationTransition/blob/master/FlipNavigationTransition/FlipPopTransitioningAnimator.swift and here is a SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890624/how-to-change-for-3d-rotation-on-uipangesture Good luck!

Comment: @dfd, that second link looks very promising. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you get it working, post an answer. I'll definitely upvote it.

Comment: @dfd, decided to write it myself. Check out the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up writing it myself. The code is pretty long, so here's a link to [the full program](https://github.com/danielVebman/iOS-Related/blob/master/InteractiveFlipAnimator.swift) on GitHub. Here are the key parts:

Everything is encapsulated in an `InteractiveFlipAnimator` object that takes a front view (`v1`) and a back view (`v2`). Each view also gets a black cover that functions as a shadow to add that darkening effect when the view turns in perspective.

Here is the panning function:

```
/// Add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the main view that contains the card and pass it onto this function.
@objc func pan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let view = gesture.view else { return }
    if isAnimating { return }

    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    let x = translation.x
    let angle = startAngle + CGFloat.pi * x / view.frame.width

    // If the angle is outside [-pi, 0], then do not rotate the view and count it as touchesEnded. This works because the full width is the screen width.
    if angle < -CGFloat.pi || angle > 0 {
        if gesture.state != .began && gesture.state != .changed {
            finishedPanning(angle: angle, velocity: gesture.velocity(in: view))
        }
        return
    }

    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    // Perspective transform
    transform.m34 = 1 / -500
    // y rotation transform
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0)
    self.v1.layer.transform = transform
    self.v2.layer.transform = transform

    // Set the shadow
    if startAngle == 0 {
        self.v1Cover.alpha = 1 - abs(x / view.frame.width)
        self.v2Cover.alpha = abs(x / view.frame.width)
    } else {
        self.v1Cover.alpha = abs(x / view.frame.width)
        self.v2Cover.alpha = 1 - abs(x / view.frame.width)
    }

    // Set which view is on top. This flip happens when it looks like the two views make a vertical line.
    if abs(angle) < CGFloat.pi / 2 {
        // Flipping point
        v1.layer.zPosition = 0
        v2.layer.zPosition = 1
    } else {
        v1.layer.zPosition = 1
        v2.layer.zPosition = 0
    }

    // Save state
    if gesture.state != .began && gesture.state != .changed {
        finishedPanning(angle: angle, velocity: gesture.velocity(in: view))
    }
}
```

The code to finish panning is very similar, but it is also much longer. To see it all come together, visit the GitHub link above.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21263238)

Comment: @ArnabHore, is that better now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Links can break over time so its best to keep the core details in the answer itself

Comment: @Daniel any possibility of converting this to support LTR language? I want to implement it to an Arabic app and want the animation other way round.